# update multiple documents with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, es6-promise

How to iterate an array of objects to update documents with mongodb and **keep the modified documents to return back in the response**

Notice the comments in the code

```
.put(function (req, res) {

    var data = req.body.data;
    var documents = [];
    for (var item in data) {

        var id = data[item]._id;
        var document = data[item];

        Item.update({ _id: id }, document, { overwrite: true }, function (err, item) {
          if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'Error'});
          }
          Item.findById(id, function (err, document) {
            if (err) {
              res.send({});
            }
            documents.push(document); // documents are pushed
          });

        });        
    }
    documents ; // value is []
    res.json({
      items: documents
    });        
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) instead. As long as your enviroment supports the ES6 contructs, or you import something that provides the `Promise.all()`:

```js
Promise.all(
    req.body.data.map(function(doc) {
        var id = doc._id;
        delete doc._id;
        return Item.findByIdAndUpdate(id,doc,{ "new": true });
    })
).then(function(documents) {
    res.json({ "items": documents })
});
```

No need for external libraries.

Comment: that seems a better solution, but "return Item.findByIdAnUpdate(id,doc,{ "new": true });" is throwing an exception: "Type error is not a function" instead I change it for "return {test:"test"}" and works fine.

Comment: @Jordi "typo" `.findByIdAndUpdate()` and not `.findByIdAnUpdate()` which was missing the `"d"` in `"And"`. The whole points "was" and "is" that you both do not need additional imports, and that secondly the `.findByIdAndUpdate()` is better than seperate operations of `.update()` and `.findById()`. Not only two trips to the server instead of one, but also is not "truly" the document in the state directly after the modification is made. Other operations could have possibly modified within the two. But this is not the case for any of the `.find**AndUpdate()` varaints.

Comment: Yes, was a I "typo" mistake, sorry and thanks @BlakesSeven.

Answer (score 1):

Since `update` is async, your `documents` is empty and return immediately. Create promises for each of the update. Also create a outer promise array. Push these promises to this array, and send the response when all are done. I am using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

```
.put(function (req, res) {

    var data = req.body.data;
    var documents = [];
    var promises = []
    for (var item in data) {

        var id = data[item]._id;
        var document = data[item];
        var itemDefer = Q.defer();

        Item.update({ _id: id }, document, { overwrite: true }, function (err, item) {
          if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'Error'});
          }
          Item.findById(id, function (err, document) {
            if (err) {
              itemDefer.reject(err);
            }
            itemDefer.resolve(document);
          });
        });  
        promises.push(itemDefer.promise);      
    }
    Q.all(promises).then(function(documents) {
        res.json({items: documents});    
    }, then(function(err) {
        res.send({})
    }))

})
```